# Does a pointer extend the lifetime of an automatic-storage variable?

Tags: c++, variables, pointers, storage, automatic-storage

```
int main() 
{
    float* ptr;

    {
        float f{10.f};
        ptr = &f;
    }

    *ptr = 13.f;
    // Do more stuff with `*ptr`...
}
```

**It it valid or undefined behavior to use/access `*ptr`?**

I tested situations similar to the above example and everything seems to work as if the lifetime of the variable in the nested block was extended thanks to the pointer.

I know that `const&` (const references) will extend the lifetime of a temporary. Is this the same for pointers?

Comment: Where did you get the information about `const &` extending the lifetime of the referenced temporary? I think, it's not true.

Comment: @TilmanVogel http://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/

Comment: "Does a pointer extend the lifetime of an automatic-storage variable?" - no.

Comment: @TilmanVogel It **is** true. A pointer, however, is **not** a reference.

Comment: The connection with references is tenuous at best. Your question is not about temporary values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's undefined behavior because you are accessing an object that has been deallocated.

The variable `f` is declared within that specific block of scope. When the execution flow reaches:

```
*ptr = 13.f;
```

the object has been deallocated and `ptr` points to the old address of `f`.

Therefore no, the lifetime of `f` has not been extended.

Answer (score 5):

The float will go out of scope and your pointer will reference a non-allocated memory region -> using it will lead to UB.